# Kotlin: How to ensure that both expressions are evaluated when using logical AND(&&), OR(||) operators

Tags: kotlin

I have some pseudo-code like this:

```
fun foo(): Boolean {
    println("foo")
    return true
}

fun bar() : Boolean {
    println("bar")
    return false
}

fun main() {
    if(foo() || bar()) { 
        // prints foo
    }
}
```

Inside the if statement I need both expressions to be evaluated, e.g. both `foo` and `bar` to run. However, this code  only evaluates the first expression and only `foo` gets printed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can Boolean's `or` and `and` methods, they are not short-circuiting and evaluate both expressions:

```
if(foo() or bar()) {
    // prints foo
    // prints bar
}
```

Here is the documentation for the `or` method:

```
public infix fun or(other: Boolean): Boolean
```

> Performs a logical `or` operation between this Boolean and the [other] one. Unlike the `||` operator, this function does not perform short-circuit evaluation. Both `this` and [other] will always be evaluated.

See [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/conditionals.html#comparisons) for more details

Answer (score 7):

As Max says, using [`or`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-int/or.html) is the simplest and usually the best solution.

But, because it's always worth being aware of alternatives, here's one.  You could make the calls *before* the logic:

```
val fooResult = foo()
val barResult = bar()
if (fooResult || barResult)
    // ...
```

That's longer-winded, and needs two extra variables.  But it does have the advantage that the calls are explicit; it's obvious to anyone reading the code that the methods always get called (which might not be so obvious if the reader isn't familiar with `or`).  And it gives you a place to insert debug statements if needed.

Comment: This is the generalized way to do this, as it is done in other programming languages too, while `or` is Kotlin specific.

Comment: To be fair, Kotlin's `or` is doing the same thing as the bitwise operator `|` in C and Java, so that approach isn't _that_ Kotlin-specific.  (And the difference is a little clearer; it's depressingly easy to get `|` mixed up with `||` in C/Java…)

Comment: @gidds: Using `|` for this is a bad idea in C. It doesn't support non-integer operands, and while it happens to work for integers, the similar use of `&` for non-short-circuiting AND is completely broken.